# How can I Transform a typical controller to a service / factory ANGULARJS?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-service

**Hi!
I'm doing a webapp and i need to share my array to my controllers.
Thank you.!**

```
MyControllers.controller('MyCtrl',['$scope',

function ($scope){
    $scope.items = [{id:1}, {id:2}, {id:3}];

    $scope.addNewItem = function() {
        var newItemNo = $scopeItems.length+1;
        $scope.Items.push({'id':newItemNo});
    };

    $scope.showAddItem = function(Item) {
        return Item.id === $scope.Items[$scope.Items.length-1].id;
    };
}
]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Angular factories are singleton so the data from withing the factory can be shared among all controllers. You just need to inject the factory into the controller.

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp');

myApp.factory('myService', function() {
  var _items = [{id:1}, {id:2}, {id:3}];

  return { items : _items };
});

myApp.controller('MyCtrl1',['$scope', 'myService', function ($scope, myService){
  $scope.items = myService.items;
]);

myApp.controller('MyCtrl2',['$scope', 'myService', function ($scope, myService){
  $scope.items = myService.items;
]);
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Yash.
i was confused between service and factory.

But if i want to add items to my array, i need to do something like this?

myApp.factory('myService', function($scope) {
  var _items = [{id:1}, {id:2}, {id:3}];
addItem:function($scope){ _items.push($scope.item)}


  return { items : _items };
});

Comment: Yes normally I do that too. Helps to keep the controllers lightweight.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few problems with your code. 
You have

```
var newItemNo = $scopeItems.length+1;
```

and you probably want

```
var newItemNo = $scope.Items.length+1;
```

Thanks :)

Also, for your

```
MyController.controller
```

part, you want something like

```
angular.module('appName').controller
```

Also you can inject your service into your controller or bind it to the $rootscope, but that shouldn't be needed in your case. :D

Comment: Thanks,i change the name before asking the question, i forgot the dot.

Comment: course, i want to inject my service into controller, but my problem it's "create the service".